# triggering a cli command via a restful api

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a cli command, that is supposed to create a schema and run migration migrations on a database for an application. Due to new requirements, I'm having to run migrations via an api, and this api happens to be the same api for the application. I'd like to know if it is a good pattern, or practise to invoke cli commands via a RESTful Api in such a way? What should my concerns be regarding the api and application at hand?

Comment: First concern: security. You don't want some script kiddie hitting your API and reinitializing your database.

Comment: I don't see any problem in having an online installer (many popular applications do), as long as its properly secured and it handles timeouts gracefully. For example, you can generate a file with a long random name and require such ID to be entered (site owner can see files through FTP, others can't) and prevent the installer from running if the application is already installed. But it doesn't need to be a command-line tool: you can reuse the command's logic but invoke it from your controller.